# Can't make transitions work

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've been trying to make transitions work and I had no luck, so I took this example from http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_trans_reverse and change the url to make it work locally, but nothing happened.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Click on the link to see the slide effect (slides to the next page from right to left).</p>
    <a href="test2.html" rel="external" data-transition="slide">Slide to Page Two</a>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Footer Text</h1>
  </div>
</div> 

<div data-role="page" id="pagetwo">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Click on the link to see the slide effect REVERSED (slides to the previous page from left to right).</p>
    <a href="#pageone" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Slide to Page One (reversed)</a>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Footer Text</h1>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

It just redirects without the transition animation.

I have no clue of what I'm doing wrong.

Many thanks.

Comment: W3school is not good "school" to try to learn anything.

Comment: I know, but this works online and I see nothing different from what I'm doing...and trying the same thing in my computer doesn't work.

Comment: with `rel=external` you lose transition animation as you load that page with Ajax disabled. It's similar to `data-ajax=false`.

Comment: @Omar you are right. Please, make that comment an answer and I'll mark it up. Thanks.

Comment: @Omar now I'm getting ´Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin´ , how can I solve this without the rel external?

Comment: your website should be [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) enabled to enable jQM to perform Ajax/XMLHttpRequest.